# Powershell: How to dynamically build array or objects?

Tags: arrays, powershell, reference

I would like to collect some information about hosts in the domain, so I am trying to write something like this:

```
# declare array for storing final data
$servers_list = @() 
#start with a list of servers and go through collecting the info
$servers | ForEach-Object {
  $sys = Get-WmiObject Win32_computersystem -ComputerName $_
  # create new custom object to store information
  $server_obj = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
  $server_obj | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Domain –Value $sys.Domain
  # .... add all other relevant info in the same manner

  # Add server object to the array
  $servers_list += $server_obj
 }
```

**The problem with this code is that I pass a reference to the object into array and not the actual object.** So by the time my loop is finished I end up with an array that contains rows that look all the same :(

Any idea how to pass actual object into array and not just a reference to it?
Another thought is to dynamically declare new object instead of using **$server_obj** variable every time but I am not sure how to do this either...

Thanks!!!

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?  You may need to modify the add-member line to `$server_obj = $server_obj | Add-Member ... -PassThru`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build an array of objects and keep dynamically adding information to them like this:

```
#This will be your array of objects 
#In which we will keep adding objects from each computer
$Result = @() 

#start with a list of servers and go through collecting the info
$servers | ForEach-Object {

     $sys = Get-WmiObject Win32_computersystem -ComputerName $_
     # create new custom object to keep adding store information to it
     $Result += New-Object –TypeName PSObject -Property @{Domain = $sys.Domain;
                                                          Name = $sys.Name;
                                                          SystemType = $sys.SystemType
                                                         }

 }

# Get back the objects 
$Result
```

Where Domain,Name and SystemType are the properties that you want to associate with the objects.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped! I tried to create a new object and added it to array in one call but I guess I was doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is passing a reference, but I don't think it's the object that's being passed as a reference, but the property values. There are discrete objects, but they all have the same reference for their property values, so they all look the same.  If that's the case,

```
$server_obj | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Domain –Value "$($sys.Domain)"
```

should make the value a string, which is a value type and won't change.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this a little harder than it should be. Pass the server names from a query, csv or list then iterate over them. Select what you want from the result.

```
$info = "server1", "server2" | ForEach-Object{Get-WmiObject  -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $_ } | Select-Object Domain, Name, Systemtype

$info[1].Domain will output domain.com
```